# How to create an integer column with default value using Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I am using Flask-Migrate (3.1.0) to handle my db(Postgres) migration for a flask application.
There's few answers on the internet but they are targeting models built using SQLAlchemy, the problem is I am building my models using Flask-SQLAlchemy, though I know there is no huge difference between them and Flask-SQLAlchemy is built on top of SQLAlchemy.

```
def class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(60), index=True)
    date_of_birth = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)
    team_member = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable = False)
    is_monitored = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False, nullable=False)
    lifecycle = db.Column(db.Integer, default= 1, nullable=False)
    shows=db.relationship('UserHistory', backref='active_state', lazy=True)`
```

Using flask db migrate to generate the migration script, I found no trace of the default value.

```
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.add_column('user', sa.Column('lifecycle', sa.Integer(), nullable=False))
    op.add_column('user_history', sa.Column('lifecycle', sa.Integer(), nullable=False))
    # ### end Alembic commands ###
```

As I define a column constraint to be not null, flask db upgrade fails which makes sense.

Is there any 'Flask-SQLAlchemy' solution to this issue rather than pure 'SQLAlchemy'? I don't know if mixing Flask-SQLAlchemy and SQLAlchemy is good idea .

Thanks

Comment: The `default` parameter affects only the Python layer.  If you want a default specified in the DDL use `server_default`.  See the docs for [Insert/Update defaults](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/defaults.html)